# What is the best way to get a reference to an Akka Actor

Tags: scala, akka

I am a little confused by how I am supposed to get a reference to my Actor once it has been crerated in the Akka system. Say I have the following:

```
class MyActor(val x: Int) extends Actor {

 def receive = {
  case Msg => doSth()
 }
}
```

And at some stage I would create the actor as follows:

```
val actorRef = system.actorOf(Props(new MyActor(2), name = "Some actor")
```

But when I need to refer to the MyActor object I cannot see any way to get it from the actor ref?

Thanks
Des

Comment: That's the whole idea.  You are not supposed to be able to get at the underlying actor class instance.  The actor ref is a lightweight proxy to your actor class instance.  Allowing people to directly access the actor instance could lead down the path of mutable data issues/concurrent state update issues and that's a bad path to go down.  By forcing you to go through the ref (and thus the mailbox), state and data will always be safe as only one message is processed at a time.

Comment: @cmbaxter this is a good answer, not a comment ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm adding my comment as an answer since it seems to be viewed as something worth putting in as an answer.

Not being able to directly access the actor is the whole idea behind actor systems. You are not supposed to be able to get at the underlying actor class instance. The actor ref is a lightweight proxy to your actor class instance. Allowing people to directly access the actor instance could lead down the path of mutable data issues/concurrent state update issues and that's a bad path to go down. By forcing you to go through the ref (and thus the mailbox), state and data will always be safe as only one message is processed at a time.

Answer (score 2):

I think cmbaxter has a good answer, but I want to make it just a bit more clear.  The ActorRef is your friend for the following reasons:

1. You cannot ever access the underlying actor.  Actors receive their thread of execution from the Dispatcher given to them when they are created.  They operate on one mailbox message at a time, so you never have to worry about concurrency inside of the actor unless YOU introduce it (by handling a message asynchronously with a Future or another Actor instance via delegation, for example).  If someone had access to the underlying class behind the ActorRef, they could easily call into the actor via a method using another thread, thus negating the point of using the Actor to avoid concurrency in the first place.
2. ActorRefs provide Location Transparency.  By this, I mean that the Actor instance could exist locally on the same JVM and machine as the actor from which you would like to send it a message, or it could exist on a different JVM, on a different box, in a different data center.  You don't know, you don't care, and your code is not littered with the details of HOW the message will be sent to that actor, thus making it more declarative (focused on the what you want to do business-wise, not how it will be done).  When you start using Remoting or Clusters, this will prove very valuable.
3. ActorRefs mask the instance of the actor behind it when failure occurs, as well.  With the old Scala Actors, you had no such proxy and when an actor "died" (threw an Exception) that resulted in a new instance of the Actor type being created in its place.  You then had to propagate that new instance reference to anyone who needed it.  With ActorRef, you don't care that the Actor has been reincarnated - it's all transparent.
4. There is one way to get access to the underlying actor when you want to do testing, using TestActorRef.underlyingActor.  This way, you can write unit tests against functionality written in methods inside the actor.  Useful for checking basic business logic without worrying about Akka dynamics.

Hope that helps.